# sed insert line command to add text with new line OSX

Tags: bash, macos, sed, insert

I'm trying to insert text to the 100th line in a file using sed, and the syntax I've found on other forums is:

```
sed -i '' "100i\ text to insert" filename
```

When I use this I am able to add text on a particular line but it affects other text which is already there and misplaces it.

I want to add a new line before and after the text added to the file.

I tried this `sed -i '' "100i\ text to insert  other text to insert" filename` but it didn't work as excepted.

This is the output when I run the above command. the order should be `<key>` and below that should be `<string>` tag.

```
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This will allow "App" to find and connect to Bluetooth accessories. This app may also use bluetooth to know when you are nearby.</string>   <string>This app requires constant access to your location in order to track your position, even when the screen is off or the app is in the background.</string>
```

I can't seem to figure out what should I add in command to add a new line.

I don't want to disturb order I just want if I am inserting text at line 100 and if there is a text already then that text should go to a new line.

I'm using OSX, which is why I have an empty ' ' as my extension.

Thanks!

Comment: `I am able to add text on a particular line but it affects other text which is already there and misplace it.`
Could you please do add samples of input and expected output in your question and let us know then?

Comment: Just press ENTER to introduce a newline

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I updated the question. can you please have a look

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your suggestion didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to add a newline, you should use: `$'\n'`; [ANSI quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48106/what-does-it-mean-to-have-a-dollarsign-prefixed-string-in-a-script)

[More SO info on sed newline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52131/sed-on-osx-insert-at-a-certain-line)

---

To answer the question; use:

```
sed -i '' -e "3s/^//p; 3s/^.*/text to insert/" /tmp/so.txt
```

1. `3s/^//p;` Duplicate line #3
2. `3s/^.*/text to insert/"` Replace newly line #3 with your text

[image]
Edit;

```
sed -i '' -e "3s/^//p; 3s/^.*/<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription<\/key>/" /tmp/so.txt
```

*Remember to escape any `/` chars!*

Comment: my command is 


`sed -i '' -e "23s/^//p; 3s/^.*/<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>/" filename `



<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key> this is the text to insert

Comment: Try with a simple `test` string. The error is probably caused by the unescaped `<` `>` `/` chars

Comment: I also think so...but anyway I want to add `<key>` tag as well  :(

Comment: @RageshPikalmunde I've updated my answer with a new comamnd/pic

Answer (score 0):

Try ed(1) if you want.

```
printf '%s\n' 3a 'text to insert' . w | ed -s file
```

Here no escaping needed.

```
printf '%s\n' '100a' '<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>' '<string>This will allow "App" to find and connect to Bluetooth accessories. This app may also use bluetooth to know when you are nearby.</string>   <string>This app requires constant access to your location in order to track your position, even when the screen is off or the app is in the background.</string>' . w | ed -s file.txt
```

... or using a Heredoc

```
ed -s file.txt <<'EOE'
100a
<key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>This will allow "App" to find and connect to Bluetooth accessories. This app may also use bluetooth to know when you are nearby.</string>   <string>This app requires constant access to your location in order to track your position, even when the screen is off or the app is in the background.</string>
.
w
EOE
```

Just replace the `file.txt` with your file name.